# Airflow SSHOperator Timeout after the task is completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am using airflow SshOperator to launch a python script.
My dag looks likes this

```
Group1 = ([GeneratedData1, GenerateData2] >> Join)
[Group1, Timeout20min] >> CheckStateOfData
```

- Timeout20min is a PythonOperator with a time.sleep(20*60)
- Join is an EmptyOperator
- The rests are SshOperator to the same remote box, where the command is `source ~/.bashrc; conda activate myenv; cd /my/folder; python my_script.py`

Both GenerateData tasks have `cmd_timeout=1800`

The issue I have is that my generateData2 always logs the normal logs of the tasks (which takes less than 10min). So I can see it arrive to the very end of my python script without any error. But it then waits for 30min (my timeout) before crashing with the following error

```
[2023-12-11, 00:08:26 UTC] {ssh.py:529} WARNING - 2023-12-11 00:08:26,033 [INFO] Finished (GenerateData2.py:252) # This is the last line of my python script
[2023-12-11, 00:38:26 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1937} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/qrt_cmmbt/.conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 178, in execute
    result = self.run_ssh_client_command(ssh_client, self.command, context=context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/scratch/qrt_cmmbt/.conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 163, in run_ssh_client_command
    exit_status, agg_stdout, agg_stderr = self.hook.exec_ssh_client_command(
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/scratch/qrt_cmmbt/.conda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 549, in exec_ssh_client_command
    raise AirflowException("SSH command timed out")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH command timed out
[2023-12-11, 00:38:26 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1400} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=my_dag, task_id=Group1.GenerateData2, execution_date=20231210T000100, start_date=20231211T000100, end_date=20231211T003826
[2023-12-11, 00:38:26 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 11089 for task Group1.GenerateData2 (SSH command timed out; 7160)
[2023-12-11, 00:38:26 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:228} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-12-11, 00:38:26 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2778} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

My DAG is also configured with a timeout `dagrun_timeout=datetime.timedelta(hours=6)` so it should be long enough not to be the issue. The previous logs come from a run started at midnight

GeneratedData2 has this behaviour everyday but I haven't been able to reproduce manually either by launching a backfill run or launching a scheduled run at another time.
Generatedat1 had the same exact issue twice in the last few weeks as well...

One possible lead might be that these python ends by doing some rsync of data to other remote boxes (with subprocess calling rsync), so I am wondering if there can be something like an ssh connection that does not close or something of this kind which makes airflow think that the process is not done?

Does anyone have experienced similar behaviour?

Thanks in advance for your help